# How to get the numbers from query in presto?

Tags: sql, url, hive, presto

for example, the query has the value:

```
currentView=/review_list_renewal_page&page=SDP&vendorItemID=3081429363&categoryID=&itemID=52159373&eventReferrer=/click_top_button&itemProductID=&pdpStyle=BRAND_SDP_FASHION&content=option_picker&type=brandSDPFashion&q=&logCategory=event&logType=click&productID=12257000&optionStatus=normal&searchId=&memberID=6339421&rank=&request_time=1487114662328&tz=+0900&appVersion=4.5.2&wl_mo=LG-F460S&wl_ma=LGE&wl_sn=Android&wl_v=5.0.1&wl_r=1440x2392&wl_l=ko&wl_c=KR
```

I used STR_TO_MAP(query, "&", "=")["productId"] to get the number mapped to productId in Hive. But now in presto, the function seems invalid. So how to retrieve it from query ? 
The query is not strict in format I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
split_to_map(query,'&','=')['productId']
```

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html

Demo

```
presto> select split_to_map('currentView=/review_list_renewal_page&page=SDP&vendorItemID=3081429363&categoryID=&itemID=52159373&eventReferrer=/click_top_button&itemProductID=&pdpStyle=BRAND_SDP_FASHION&content=option_picker&type=brandSDPFashion&q=&logCategory=event&logType=click&productID=12257000&optionStatus=normal&searchId=&memberID=6339421&rank=&request_time=1487114662328&tz=+0900&appVersion=4.5.2&wl_mo=LG-F460S&wl_ma=LGE&wl_sn=Android&wl_v=5.0.1&wl_r=1440x2392&wl_l=ko&wl_c=KR^J','&','=')['productID'];
  _col0
----------
 12257000
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please help to solve the question I just came up ?